# No value passed in parameter inflater in OnCreateOptionMenu in fragments kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, search, compiler-errors, fragment

I wanna use search button in action bar and for that I'm inflating menu in my fragments. here is my code in the picture

If i run this code then this method doesn't inflate menu item and if i remove inflater parameter then compiler says no value passed to parameter.
Now please let me know that how can i pass value to inflater or else
(Answer should be in kotlin language)

[image]

Comment: Do not post screenshots (or photos...) of your code. Post the code as text in the question and indicate where the errors are happening with comments or other annotation.

Comment: You use the ``inflater`` that's passed into the method

Comment: can you please help me with this problem @cactustictacs          temp.clear()
val searchtext= p0!!.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
if(searchtext.isNotEmpty()){
value.forEach {
if(it.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext))//this line craete error
temp.add(it)


hello
Actually I Wanna add SearchView in fragments Using Kotlin but My Code is Throwing error.here "lowercase" Code says Unresolved Reference ,Receiver type Mismatch,Now please tell me  Condition that i can put in if Condition.

Comment: Just edit your question and add the code in there, it's unreadable if you dump it in a comment like that. You're calling ``lowercase`` on something that isn't a ``String`` (or ``Char``). The error message will tell you which line number the problem is at

Comment: @cactustictacs   please refer to my question,here is the link   https://stackoverflow.com/q/70727320/16756383