# using onQueryTextChange in fragment and need some suggestions regarding code

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, android-fragments, error-handling

Actually I Wanna add SearchView in fragments Using Kotlin but nobody is telling how to do that so i was trying to use that code that used by YouTuber who was Creating Searchview in Activity.They were using a code after ForEach loop and that was if(it.lowercase(Locale.getDefault().contains(text).

So when i added this Line compiler Throwed Error that Unresolved Reference ,receiver type mismatch...so I just Wanna know what line Should i add instead of this (if i don't use this line then nothing add in my temp array)

thanks

Here is my Code :

...

Datahai class's code

class DataHai (

```
var book_id : String,

val name : String,

val author: String,

val price: String,

val rating : String,

var image: String

    )
```

dashboard  fragment

class Dashboard : Fragment() {

```
lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView // recycler view

lateinit var relativeLayout: RelativeLayout

lateinit var ada: adapter  //adapter class object

lateinit var values: DataHai

lateinit var swipe: SwipeRefreshLayout

lateinit var LayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

lateinit var value: ArrayList<DataHai>

lateinit var temp :ArrayList<DataHai>

override fun onCreateView(

    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
```

savedInstanceState: Bundle?

```
): View? {

    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,
```

container, false)

```
    value = ArrayList()

    temp= ArrayList()

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    swipe = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe)

    relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.progresslaoout)

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler)

    LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    gettingData()

    swipe.setOnRefreshListener {

        gettingData()

    }

    relativeLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val que = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity as Context)

    var url = "http://13.235.250.119/v1/book/fetch_books/"


    var jsonObjectRequest =

object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null,
```

Response.Listener {

```
            try {

                relativeLayout.visibility = View.GONE

                var success = it.getBoolean("success")

                if (success) {

                    var data = it.getJSONArray("data")

                    for (i in 0 until data.length()) 

                    {

                        var jsonobject = data.getJSONObject(i)

                        values = DataHai(
```

//
jsonobject.getString("book_id"),

```
                            jsonobject.getString("name"),

                            jsonobject.getString("author"),

                            jsonobject.getString("price"),

                            jsonobject.getString("rating"),

                            jsonobject.getString("image")


                        )


                        value.add(values)
```

//now am adding that data inside value array of Datahai class

```
                    }
```

temp.addAll(value)

```
                } else {
```

makeText(context, "some error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

```
                }
```

//
/* saying context == null*/

```
                ada = adapter(activity as Context, temp)

    /*now giving activity as context

           and adding value array that will access by adapter
```

class array*/

```
                recyclerView.adapter = ada 

     /* connecting these classes  */
```

recyclerView.layoutManager = LayoutManager

```
            } catch (e: JSONException) {

makeText(context, "some error occured",
```

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

```
            }

        }, Response.ErrorListener {


            makeText(context, "some error occured",
```

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

```
        }) {

            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String,
```

String> {

```
                val header = HashMap<String, String>()

                header.put("value-type", "application/json")

                header.put("token", " 9bf534118365f1")

                return header


            }

        }
    que.add(jsonObjectRequest)

    return view
}

fun gettingData() {

    if (Connection().ConnectionChecking(activity as Context)) {

    } else {

        var build = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)

        build.setTitle("Not Connected")

        build.setMessage("please check your internet
```

Connection")

```
        build.setPositiveButton("try again") { text, listner ->

            startActivityForResult(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0)

        }

        build.setNegativeButton("cancel") { text, listner ->

        }

        build.create()

        build.show()
    }


    swipe.isRefreshing = false

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater:
```

MenuInflater) {

```
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.icon,menu)

    var item=menu.findItem(R.id.search)

    var search=item?.actionView as SearchView

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)


    search.setOnQueryTextListener(object:SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{


        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {

          return true
        }

     
        override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {

            temp.clear()

            var text=p0?.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())

            if (text!!.isNotEmpty()) {

makeText(activity as Context, "working",
```

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

```
                value.forEach {

                    temp.add(it) //by this line data should add
```

but not added

```
                }


            }

            else {

                temp.clear()

                temp.addAll(value)

            }

            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

            return true
        }

    })

}
```

}

adapter

class adapter(var context : Context, var ada : ArrayList)
: Adapter<adapter.viewholderclass>() {

```
/*array*/


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType:
```

Int): viewholderclass {

```
    var view=
```

LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter,parent

,false)

```
    return viewholderclass(view)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewholderclass,
```

position: Int) {

```
    var id=ada[position]

    var auth=ada[position]  

                /*  now i am parsing the data from the ada array */

    holder.author.text=auth.author

    var nam=ada[position]

    holder.year.text=nam.name

    var rate=ada[position]

    holder.rating.text=rate.rating

    var pri=ada[position]

    holder.price.text=pri.price



    Picasso.get().load(id.image).into(holder.image)



}

override fun getItemCount() :Int{

    return ada.size             /* returning the size  */

}


class viewholderclass(view: View) :
```

RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

```
    var year=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)

    var author=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.author)

    var rating=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rating)

    var price=view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.price)

    var image=view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)

    var layout =view.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.adapter)

}
```

}

...

Comment: What type is `value`?

Comment: searchtext will get string,then i have to validate that does value's (value is an array who is storing all value that will pass in adapter class ) it contain it or not . you can just tell me the condition that i should put in if

Comment: @Tenfour04 I hope you understood about your comment

Comment: An Array of what type? If it isn’t an Array of Strings, that would explain your problem.

Comment: It's data class type array like this var value=arrayOf<Datahai>()....here Datahai is my data class name

Comment: And does it have a function called `lowercase()`? If not, that’s what the error is telling you.

Comment: It don't have that function....bro i know what error wanna say okay... that's why i want a code that can behave similar to that line and can validate that searchtext contains that data that foreach loop's it has

Comment: You’ll have to share the code of this Datahai class and what exactly about this class you want to check for us to be able to help.

Comment: Can you please text me on my telegram there i can give you any code that you want....@Shivam@8860 i am waiting please text me brother, i am also facing an issue while integrating fb login, i wanna discuss this also from you so please text

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code. I don’t have time to sit and work through your issues in real time.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have added all code,please take a look and also let me know if anything you wanna ask or need..Thankyou

Comment: Only needed to see Datahai class. Still need " what exactly about this class you want to check for". For example, when searching, do you want to search all of its properties, or only its `name`?

Comment: i wanna search only it's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original code in your question:

```
value.forEach {        
    if(it.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext)) { 
        temp.add(it)
    }
}
```

Since `value` is a list of `Datahai`, then inside the lambda, `it` is a Datahai, not a String, so you can't call `lowercase` on it. You said in the comments you want to search the `name` property only, so you only need to get the `name` and compare that:

```
value.forEach {        
    if(it.name.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext)) { 
        temp.add(it)
    }
}
```

Your code would be a little simpler using `filterTo` instead of `forEach`:

```
value.filterTo(temp) {        
    it.name.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchtext))
}
```

Comment: wow it is finally working ...Thankyou sooo much...can i ask you one more question?,it is very simple for you its related to fb login ....please

Comment: Just post another question on the site here so everyone will see it. I don’t use Facebook.

Comment: ok.I'll post it after some hours and also will share you link here in comments...doubt is related to integrating Fb login feature in my app (continue with facebook button)